Can I control packet distribution from raw socket to multiple threads?
I am writing a program that reads from a raw socket, and handles packets.
My problem is when scaling it (due to performance) to multiple threads, the packets will need to be distributed according to their four tuple.
Currently it seems that packets are distributed randomly between the threads.
I know I could create a dispatch thread that implements this logic, but I also read that some NICs should support this (what is called RSS), and cant figure out how to utilize it in linux (specifically I am running ubuntu 22.04).
Is there a way to do that (that does not require the dispatch thread)?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want (e.g. which language you're using). Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Have you confirmed that your NIC supports RSS? you can use ethtool for this.

How are you currently capturing packets from the socket? using any specific library e.g libcap or raw sockets with recvfrom / recvmsg?
